# No hats on meta?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2014

I am unwontedly pretty, on account of my stylish new hat collection, everywhere except meta sites.

Is this intentional? Is meta just tooooo serious for such trivialities?

(tentatively tagging as a bug)

Comment: status-by-design

Comment: There are hats on [meta.se], just not on "normal" meta sites.

Comment: [Very related](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14640/userscript-to-show-winterbash-hats-on-meta-sites).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have asked internally, and it seems nobody remembers the reason why we've always disabled hats on child metas. And so I've enabled them now. You wear the same hat on the child meta that you wear on the parent site, and the hat count on a meta user profile takes you to your hat rack on the parent site, similar to how it works for profile editing.

Comment: @balpha what about earning hats from meta answers?

Comment: @gideon No, hats are only awarded for activities on the main site unless they're specifically awarded for meta activity (and even then, they are awarded on the main site). Last year we had one or two of those, this year there aren't any.

Answer (score 14):

None of the child-meta sites have hats (that is, metas that are attached to a Q&A site).

These are where we discuss the main sites, and can discuss the hats we got on them. Given that most meta sites have vastly less traffic and activity than their main sites - it is better to leave hats just for the main sites.

Comment: Even better would be if we didn't have questions about hats on meta - currently 4 out of the 5 last active questions are about winter bash which arguably doesn't have much to do with discussion about SO. Can't we migrate them all to meta.SE as they are about the whole network anyways?

Comment: @l4mpi - so, MSE should be inundated with winterbash questions from across the network? This is fine where it is.

Comment: Yes, better MSE than MSO. Most of these questions, e.g. "OMG I earned a secret hat", "OMG I don't see my hat", "OMG I found a bug with hats" et cetera are probably duplicated on all child metas where hats are enabled right now. I'd guess it would make more sense to have them all in one place on MSE.

Comment: And yet, that's more confusing to users who may not be aware of MSE (or even just marginally aware of their own meta)

Comment: Well, sounds like a great possiblility to teach these folks about MSE and meta in general...

Comment: We really don't want people to stray out of their community - they don't need to know about MSE. Sure, if they are looking for ti they will find it - but no need to shove them to it.

Comment: OK, thanks. Can hats be earnt on meta? (E.g., hats for *getting a silver badge*?)

Comment: @Oded so if someone has a question about the entire stack exchange system, you'd rather they stay out of MSE and stay in their own local community?  ... is the goal to keep undesirables out of MSE or something?

Comment: @Yakk - nothing like that. Just that questions that are _appropriate_ on a site can stay there. There is no reason to migrate stuff that is just fine where it is, right? If someone knows about MSE and the question fits MSE - by all means, they can ask there. I am just talking about migrating stuff that doesn't need migration.

Answer (score 10):

There you go Sir Chiastic-Security!

[image]

This is the best they had a short notice:

[image]

Comment: I also require a flagon of mead brought to me on a silver platter by a busty wench.

Comment: @chiastic-security I hope you're happy now!!!!

Answer (score 0):

## Hats are now back on meta.

I checked my meta profile today and I have my hat !!! Hurray.